# filter array by key

Tags: php, arrays, array-filter

I have this little function to filter my array by keys:

```
 private function filterMyArray( )
 {
      function check( $v )
      {
           return $v['type'] == 'video';
      }
      return array_filter( $array, 'check' );
 }
```

This works great but since I have more keys to filter, I was thinking in a way to pass a variable from the main function: `filterMyArray($key_to_serch)` without success, also I've tried a global variable, but seems not work.

Due some confusion in my question :), I need something like this:

```
 private function filterMyArray( $key_to_serch )
 {
      function check( $v )
      {
           return $v['type'] == $key_to_serch;
      }
      return array_filter( $array, 'check' );
 }
```

Any idea to pass that variable?

Comment: mmm ... nested functions ... not pretty, especially when php provides functions that do this for you. try array_map() or array_filter() with lambda/closure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where anonymous functions in **PHP 5.3** come in handy (note the use of `use`):

```
private function filterMyArray($key)
{
     return array_filter(
         $array,
         function check($v) use($key) {
             return $v['type'] == $key;
         }
     );
}
```

Comment: Pfff, PHP devs should stop putting stuff into the language that shouldn't be there XD

Comment: This is where identation comes in place: this code is very hard to understand (for me) if it's not properly indented. I've just modified identation, roll back if you think yours is easier to read

Answer (score 0):

```
private function filterMyArray($key_to_search) {
  function check( $v ) {
       return $v[$key_to_search] == 'video';
  }
  return array_filter( $array, 'check' );
}
```

should work because the inner function has access to the variables in the outer function

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `use` keyword to get the variable in scope, c.f. this [example in php's doc](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php#example-154).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a PHP < 5.3 version using [create_function](http://php.net/create_function).

```
private function filterMyArray( $key)
{
      $fn = create_function( '$v', "return $v[$key] == 'video';");
      return array_filter( $array, $fn);
}
```

Comment: Actually, this will not work because the dollar signs inside the double-quoted string will be seen as variable references.